# LeetCode 1202. Smallest String With Swaps, time limit exceeded problem using Python3

Tags: python

The problem is to use UnionFind to solve the problem.
Below is the correct solution:

```
class UnionFind:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.arr = [i for i in range(n)]
    
    def find(self, x):
        if self.arr[x] == x:
            return x
        self.arr[x] = self.find(self.arr[x])
        return self.arr[x]  # this is the correct find()
    
    def union(self, x, y):
        rootX = self.find(x)
        rootY = self.find(y)
        if rootX != rootY:
            self.arr[rootY] = rootX

class Solution:
    def smallestStringWithSwaps(self, s: str, pairs: List[List[int]]) -> str:
        size = len(s)
        m = UnionFind(size)
        for x,y in pairs:
            m.union(x, y)
        
        dict = defaultdict(list)
        for i in range(size):
            root = m.find(i) 
            dict[root].append(s[i])

        for key in dict:
            dict[key].sort(reverse=True)
        
        result = []
        for i in range(size):
            root = m.find(i)
            result.append(dict[root].pop())
        
        return ''.join(result)
```

I kept getting the "time limit exceeded" error if my find() in UnionFind Class is either:

```
def find(self, x):
    if self.arr[x] == x:
        return x
    return self.find(self.arr[x]) # time limit exceeded error will occur
```

or

```
def find(self, x):
    while x != self.root[x]:
        x = self.root[x]
    return x  # time limit exceeded error will occur
```

There are total 36 test cases for this problem. Using the two find methods above will only get 35/36 passed.
So what's the difference between the correct find() and the two above?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your time-limit-exceeding versions (more or less equivalent to each other) are giving up on path compression, which avoids repeating the work of going up a long path to the root of a tree by making every node a direct child of its root whenever it’s working with that node. Normally that means getting O(log n) operations instead of (practically) O(1) operations, which wouldn’t be a big deal, but your implementation of Union is also suboptimal in that it doesn’t take into account the differences between the two trees it’s merging, so the combination is very slow – O(n) worst case for each operation, pretty much defeating the point of using a union-find structure in the first place.

For detailed explanations, the terms to look up are:

- union by weight
- union by rank
- path compression